# How to create password-protected zip in maven

Tags: maven, zip

currently I am using maven-assembly-plugin to create a zip file via "mvn clean package". The whole process works fine, the zip contains everything I need but a new requirement asks to create this zip file password-protected. I googled but not found any useful; is there anyone who needed to perform this task ?

Current plugin is defined in this way:

```
<build>
...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>create-distribution</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

and zip.xml is defined in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2
      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd"
>
  <id>zip</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>directory1/</outputDirectory>
      <directory>directory1</directory>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>config.properties</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>    
  </fileSets>
  <files>
    <file>
    <source>target/data-jar-with-dependencies.jar</source>
    <destName>data-jar-with-dependencies.jar</destName>
    </file>
  </files>

</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use an external program to unzip and zip the archive again. For example 7z:

7z e Unprotected.zip
7z a Protected.zip -pPASSWORD UNPROTECTEDFILENAME

If you want to integrate it in the build lifecycle then you need the maven exec-plugin to execute those two commands after the package phase.